# Webpack React - Html Loader Issue

Tags: angular, webpack, angularjs-directive

./legacy/src/User/UserDirective.tpl.html:1:1 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> {{ vm.fullName }}

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example